# Blurred background using only XML in android

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am using `FrameLayout` for different layers of layout. Here is my code :

```
<FrameLayout>

  <!-- Bottom layer -->
  <RelativeLayout>
      // some views and viewgroups
  </RelativeLayout>



  <!-- Middlelayer -->
  <RelativeLayout>
      // this layer will be empty.
      // I want to make this layer like frosted glass to get blur effect
  </RelativeLayout>



  <!-- Top layer -->
  <RelativeLayout>
      // some views
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**This is how I want it to look:**

[image]

I want to make the middle layer act like a frosted glass so that the bottom layer looks blurred. How can I implement it using xml only? (If not possible using only xml please help me with java code)

Comment: https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-background-blur

Answer (score 0):

Android unfortunately doesn't really support blurring natively in the way that e.g. iOS and CSS on the web do.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the alpha attribute in your XML

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

or just a background color in your code

```
v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

Where `v` is your Middlelayer

Comment: using alpha didn't blur. It just sets the transparency